# Unable to pull sqlite data from Heroku when cloning

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, heroku

I have deployed a Flask app to heroku with the below structure. In the `app` folder, you'll notice an sqlite database file `site.db`, which I created using `flask_sqlalchemy`. The database contains a table which stores login credentials (email and password) when people register an account on my web app (think of it like a social media site).

My app is successfully deployed to heroku. When I register a user account on my web app, I am able to use those email/password to log into my web app. However, when I do `heroku git:clone -a my-app-name` to pull the app to my local machine and run it locally, I'm unable to log in with the same email/password that I registered on the deployed version of my web app (my-app-name.herokuapp.com). Does anyone know why this may be the case? When I use git clone, Heroku seems to be pulling all files, including `site.db`, but the email/password I registered on the deployed app doesn't seem to be stored in login table.

I ask this question because in future if I need to make some changes to my social media site, I will use git clone to pull the app locally, make changes to my code, and then push it back to heroku master. But I don't want existing users to lose their login credentials just because I had to make an update to the app. Thanks!

```
├── Procfile
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── routes.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── site.db
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── main.css
│   │   └── profile_pics
│   │       ├── 04e2e4347d6947a2.png
│   │       ├── 0bca0a62856cdc6e.png
│   │       └── default.jpg
│   └── templates
│       ├── about.html
│       ├── account.html
│       ├── home.html
│       ├── layout.html
│       ├── login.html
│       └── register.html
├── requirements.txt
└── run.py
```

Comment: "When I register a user account on my web app, I am able to use those email/password to log into my web app"—only temporarily. Every time your dyno resets (at least once per day), your user registration will be lost.

Comment: @Chris yeah, I think I found a workaround where I use Heroku's built-in postgres service.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only solution is to use Heroku's provided postgres data store. Then you can set app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = link_to_db